# What is the meaning of the parts of a Slack API timestamp when it has a dot in it?

Tags: timestamp, slack-api

When working with the Slack API, some things like messages have a timestamp property with `ts` in its name, and the value is a string containing two numbers separated by a dot. Ex "`1355517523.000005`". What is the meaning of each of those parts?

I tried looking at the docs for some of those responses, such as [the docs for the `message` event](https://api.slack.com/events/message), but it doesn't seem to spell it out very clearly what each of the numbers mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by googling "`slack message url timestamp format`" in this issue ticket: [Timestamp type inconsistency #7](https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/7)- particularly, in [this comment](https://github.com/slackhq/slack-api-docs/issues/7#issuecomment-67913241) by Paul Hammond. As stated in the docs, these types of timestamps uniquely identify messages within a channel.

What *isn't* stated in the docs (at least- not at the time of this writing) is that the first number- the one before the dot- is a UNIX timestamp, and the second part is a further disambiguator about what order things happened in when two things have the same timestamp (even then, there's still an order in which the events happened (I assume as seen by the Slack server)). Presumably, a lower number in that part indicates that something happened earlier, and a higher number that something happened later.